# Can we keep “DATA_PUMP_DIR” and Datafile at different storage on amazon RDS oracle?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am facing low diskspace alert on amazon RDS storage and my database has high volumn fragmentation. I want to perform export-import process to remove fragmetation from database but wan't be able to do cause “DATA_PUMP_DIR” and Datafile are using same diskspace location. Can we keep “DATA_PUMP_DIR”  and Datafile on different storage on amazon RDS?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I run a lot of Oracle on EC2, but none on RDS, so I don't know much about it.  However, why don't you just do 'alter table table_name move;' followed by index rebuilds of all indexes on the table?  I think that will achieve what you want without having to do expdp/impdp at all.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I have around 15-20 tables which has high fragmentation. I was thinking that i can remove all the fragmentation with one process(expdp/impdp) rather than executing  "alter table " statements for each table.

Comment: It's entirely up to you.  I was just making a suggestion.  Depending on uptime requirements, it may be better to do one table at a time.  But again, entirely up to you.